# Create a link from an image in a cell of a table

Tags: html, image

I have access to a portion of a website where I can only drop in a piece of HTML to try and spruce it up a little. I want to create a frame of images 2x1 and when you click on an image it opens up the full image somehow.

I need to keep this basic, i.e. no CSS or scripts as my ability and the systems only allows me to do so much.

This is what has been accomplished thus far, but I am now a little stuck.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <table align=center>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=1>
        <img src="...." border=0 height=auto width=100%></img>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <img src="...." border=0 height=auto width=100%></img>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: <a href="bigImg.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="smallImg.gif" /></a>

Comment: Thanks that has done the trick.

Comment: @mplungjan what about if I wanted to put in a hover image as well? Can that be done?

Comment: Not without some css or js

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks

Comment: @mplungjan sorry last question, please forgive my dumbness, but if I wanted to add in the javascript, how would i do it?

Comment: I'll look later. You said you were limited to HTML - if you can add external or inline js then you can have a hover light box

Comment: inline would be good. :-)

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=css+hover+image+stackoverflow